# The operator norm of a linear functional bounded by the Minkowski functional defined by the Cesaro average

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

I am studying the existence of Banach limit, and I have figured out most of the things, except for one point. The following describes my question:

Let $V:=\ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, and for $\mathbf{x}\in V$, we define $$p(\mathbf{x}):=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x(k).$$ I have proved that $p(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})\leq p(\mathbf{x})+p(\mathbf{y})$ and $p(\lambda\mathbf{x})=\lambda p(\mathbf{x})$ for any $\lambda\in [0,\infty)$, i.e. $p$ is a Minkowski functional on $V$.

Now, I need to prove that

> Let $L:\ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional such that $L(\mathbf{x})\leq p(\mathbf{x})$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in V$. Then, $L$ is continuous and $\|L\|_{V^{*}}\leq 1.$

I know that, if you work backwards from the Banach limit, the dual norm here is exactly $1$. But I am working in the converse direction, and the only thing I know is what was given in the statement.

---

I have proved the continuity, but I am not sure if I am correct:

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $$\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_{V}=\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x(k)-y(k)|<\delta\ \ \text{for some}\ \ \delta>0.$$ Then,
\begin{align*}
|L(\mathbf{x})-L(\mathbf{y})|=|L(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})|\leq |p(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})|&=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x(k)-y(k)|\\
&\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot n\cdot \sup_{k=1}^{n}|x(k)-y(k)|\\
&\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot n\cdot \sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x(k)-y(k)|\\
&<\delta. 
\end{align*}

This means that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can set $\delta:=\epsilon$ so that $$\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),\ \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|_{V}<\delta\implies |L(\mathbf{x})-L(\mathbf{y})|<\epsilon,$$ and hence $L$ is continuous.

**Is this proof okay?** I am not sure of this because I am not sure if $|L(\mathbf{x})|\leq |p(\mathbf{x})|$ is true.

---

Then, I do not know how to prove $\|L\|_{V^{*}}\leq 1$. The only thing I can think of is that as $V\neq \{0\}$, we can write $$\|L\|_{V^{*}}=\sup_{\|\mathbf{x}\|_{V}=1}|L(\mathbf{x})|=\sup_{\substack{\mathbf{x}\in V \\ \sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|x(k)|=1}}|L(\mathbf{x})|,$$ but I don't know what to do next. **Any idea?**

---

I am not sure if these are needed, but using only linearity of $L$ and $L\leq p$, I have proved that

> 1. For all $\mathbf{x}\in \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $$\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}x(k)\leq L(\mathbf{x})\leq \limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}x(k).$$
> 2. $L$ is shift-invariant, i.e. $L\circ S=L$ where $S$ is the shift operator defined as $$S((x(1), x(2),\cdots))=(x(2), x(3),\cdots).$$

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have the stronger condition $|L(x)|\leq p(x)$?

Comment: @K.Power No. I have double checked it several times, but no...

Comment: @K.Power I cannot find a counterexample to show that we must need $|L(x)|\leq p(x)$, either..

Comment: Do you mean $p(\mathbf{x}):=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x(k)|$, with an absolute value in the sum?

Comment: @MikeF no. $p(x)$ does not have the absolute value in the sum.

Comment: @K.Power why deleted the answer..

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I was assuming homogeneity in that answer, but I don't think we have it unfortunately

Comment: @K.Power what do you mean by homogeneity? Perhaps we actually have it but I did not write it clearly? I am sorry I didnt read through your answer before it had been deleted...

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I mean that $p(\lambda x)=\lambda p(x)$ for all constants $\lambda$, but we actually only have it for positive constants, which I actually see you had already mentioned. I will think if I can adapt my argument.

Comment: @K.Power oh okay.. well I really appreciate the effort you made for my stupid question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you are overthinking it.  Notice that for every $x$ in $\ell ^\infty ({\mathbb R})$, and every $n\in {\mathbb N}$,
one has that
$$
  \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n x(k) \leq    \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \|x\|_\infty   = \|x\|_\infty .
  $$
Therefore $p(x)\leq \|x\|_\infty $, and hence
$$
  L(x) \leq  p(x) \leq  \|x\|_\infty .
  $$

Replacing $x$ with $-x$,  we also get
$$
  -L(x)=  L(-x) \leq  \|-x\|_\infty  =  \|x\|_\infty ,
  $$
so actually
$$
  |L(x)|\leq  \|x\|_\infty ,
  $$
whence  $\|L\|\leq 1$.

Comment: nice answer! So similarly to prove the continuity, we have $$|L(x-y)|\leq \|x-y\|_{\infty},$$ and then everything follows.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Remember that any bounded linear functional is automatically continuous! But yes that argument would also work.

Comment: @K.Power yeah you are right. I was being dumb :)

Comment: That is correct.  A single inequality takes care of it all.

Comment: @Ruy thanks. really nice answer :)